# Phone stuck in bootloop after installing Chainfire 3D app

Tags: boot-loop

I have Micromax A61 with 4.1 Jelly Bean. I rooted it using Kingo Root. I tried a performance boosting app called [Chainfire 3D](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1087427). Now it's stuck in boot screen.

I don't have CWM or TWRP recovery and USB debugging is OFF.
Help me.

Comment: Try a factory reset and cache wipe

Comment: Hard Reset or wiping Cache is not useful.

Comment: u can also download custom ROM from outside & install it on ur phone.
try it. It can be happen useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [an answer by 'Same error but solved it' on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102194/2821954),

> 1. Follow [this tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVXX-YdhRU0) to install and open a program which you will use to **uninstall** the driver of ChainFire installed on your device.
> 2. Start your phone into recovery mode (Home + Vol up + Power).
> 3. Plug in your phone via USB cord to your computer.
> 4. Once you have ADB opened in command prompt, type `su` to gain superuser access.
> 5. After that, you type `cd /system/lib`
> 6. Then you type `cf3d_uninstall.sh`
>
> Source: [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2362873)

Comment: Can you replace the video with something better

Comment: @SuiciDoga You can learn it from https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_HowTo.html . It is text. Read it and install sdk. Don't forget to install USB driver for your device.